# Spotify WebApi Can't Fetch User Playlists Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify, spotify-app

I am making a spotify clone using react.js and adding some functionality in it using spotify API
I used `spotify-web-api-js` package to handle user authentication and other functionality.

But I can't fetch user playlist data to show on side bar, I followed the documentation [here](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node#usage), the method I used seems correct to me,

code snippet given in documentation

```
// Get a user's playlists
spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists('thelinmichael')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Retrieved playlists', data.body);
  },function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  });
```

when I console log the result I get some data but it doesn't contain the user's playlists

code snippet for fetching playlists, in this code user is fetched perfectly fine

```
// IMPORT AND VARIABLES
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";
const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();

// SETTING USER
spotify.setAccessToken(_token);

spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SET_USER",
    user: user,
  });
});

spotify
  .getUserPlaylists()
  .then((playlists) => {
    console.log("get playlists", playlists);
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
      playlists: playlists.body,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("playlist err", err));
```

console log of playlist result, it doesn't have any body as shown in documentation we need to use `.body` of result

```
{
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ut4muuidtha4hcgtknh2diiqu/playlists?offset=0&limit=20", 
items: Array(0), 
limit: 20, 
next: null, 
offset: 0, 
…
}
```

in scopes I have used these,

```
const scopes = [
  "playlist-read-private",
  "user-read-currently-playing",
  "user-read-recently-played",
  "user-read-playback-state",
  "user-top-read",
  "user-modify-playback-state",
];
```

I have also uploaded by code [here](https://github.com/sachuverma/All-Clones/tree/master/spotify-clone) if you can check from there, deployed [here](https://spotify-clone-8063e.web.app/)

Answer (score 1):

I've been following the same tutorial based on your code (Sonny Sangha/Clever Programmer one).

The other answers are incorrect: providing a user ID isn't the issue because we're fetching the currently logged in user's playlist, which can be done without parameters.

I noticed that you're looking at the wrong documentation for `spotify-web-js`. You linked: thelinmichael's `spotify-web-js-node` documentation, not JMPerez's `spotify-web-api-js` documentation, which is actually here, and slightly different:
https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js

The documentation has a section that says:

> Some functions don't need to receive the user's id as a parameter, and will use the user's information from the access token:

```
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
spotifyApi.setAccessToken('<here_your_access_token>');
spotifyApi
  .getUserPlaylists() // note that we don't pass a user id
  .then(
    function (data) {
      console.log('User playlists', data);
    },
    function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
```

Modify your code to:

```
// IMPORT AND VARIABLES
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";
const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();

// SETTING USER
spotify.setAccessToken(_token);

spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SET_USER",
    user: user,
  });
});

spotify
  .getUserPlaylists()
  .then((playlists) => {
    console.log("get playlists", playlists);
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
      playlists: playlists,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("playlist err", err));`
```

i.e. remove the `.body` part of the playlists dispatch. This function will hold the playlists in an `items` array:
[image: Console log of playlists being displayed]

Which you access like this in the next part of the tutorial:

```
{
    playlists?.items?.map(playlist => (
        <SidebarOption title={ playlist.name } key={ playlist.name } />
    ))
}
```

Note that he didn't add a key in the tutorial, but it's good practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In the doc you mentioned there are some parameters in the getUserPlaylist() function, but you haven't provided any, re-check that thing

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that you forgot to pass the user id like `thelinmichael` in the example (`spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists('thelinmichael')`). In your case, there are no parameters. Therefore, I assume the API is going to use your own user id. As you can see from the [Spotify Developer Console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-playlists/?user_id=ut4muuidtha4hcgtknh2diiqu&limit=&offset=), there are no playlists associated with this user id. If you pass in the desired user id as a parameter, your query should work.

```
// IMPORT AND VARIABLES
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";
const spotify = new SpotifyWebApi();

// SETTING USER
spotify.setAccessToken(_token);

spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SET_USER",
    user: user,
  });
});

// USER ID TO QUERY PLAYLISTS FROM
const userId = "XXXXXXX";

spotify
  .getUserPlaylists(userId)
  .then((playlists) => {
    console.log("get playlists", playlists);
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
      playlists: playlists.body,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("playlist err", err));
```